# "BigInt is not defined" in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to use a BigInt value in React, and it is returning an error that BigInt is not defined. We are using node version 14.14.0, and BigInt is supposed to be supported as of 10.4. It's not a browser issue because 1) the latest firefox supports BigInt and 2) the app is failing to compile, so the browser isn't loading the page. I'm using es2020, and it is still failing to recognize the constructor.

What else do I need to do to get the compiler to recognize BigInt?

.eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2020": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2020,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy":"http://appip:8080",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "braintree-web-drop-in": "^1.23.0",
    "eth-sig-util": "^3.0.1",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-formik-ui": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "web3": "^1.2.9",
    "yup": "^0.29.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=./.cert/file.pem SSL_KEY_FILE=./.cert/file.pem react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "prettier": "2.0.5"
  }
}
```

line throwing error:

```
const wholeCoinsBigInt = BigInt(amount.amount);
```

error:

```
Line 49:30:  'BigInt' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: Please share your build error.

Comment: I did, but I added it at the bottom for additional clarity.

Comment: Your title is wrong. There is no bigint define in React. it's js Primitive time.

Comment: Also, please create a [mcve] here, not even so much "for us", but "for yourself": forcing yourself to run through the minimizing exercise almost _always_ lets you find the error on your own. Copy your dir to a new dir, and start removing almost everything until you're basically left with about 3 lines of code in this particular case. And if you haven't, you have the perfect code to put in your post.

Comment: Where/when does the error occur? This can also come from ESLint.

Comment: @underscore it's also a linting error, not at all related to React.

Comment: I'm guessing babel doesn't know how to handle it. Try this suggestion: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28492#issuecomment-733801950

Comment: @SteveHynding there isn't a babel config file in the source folder. I saw that while researching, but wasn't sure what to do with it because the only config files are the eslint and the package.json files.

Comment: The error is coming from when I added the BigInt constructor to one of the js pages in the app. Everything worked fine up to that point, but when I added in the BigInt constructor it started throwing the error and failed to compile. From the research I've done it is usually caused by either a not updated node version or the eslint version, but both of those are on the correct version, so I'm not sure what else to check.

Comment: If you used create-react-app to start the project, you likely have webpack handling the babel transforms. If there isn't a webpack config file in your project root, you should be able to create one to automagically add or overwrite the default config

Comment: It was created using create-react-app, so I'll look into the webpack config. The front end and the express server are separated into different folders, and the issue is strictly on the front end side of things. I tried requiring babel and using the bigint plugin, but got the error "Uncaught Error: Cannot load plugin @babel/plugin-syntax-bigint relative to / in a browser" which doesn't mean anything to me because I'm not used to JS needing to be compiled. Having to compile JS is new to me; I'm used to it working as written in the browser with the occasional need for a polyfill.

Comment: Your configuration does seem like it should work. One option is to explicitly add the globals to your `eslintrc.json` file like so `"globals": { "BigInt": "readonly" }`. See: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#using-configuration-files-1